# how to fix No Internet: ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: browsermob-proxy, selenoid

1. started Selenoid

./cm selenoid start --vnc

2. started BMP container

docker run -p 58080:8080 -p 58200:8200 --name browser-mob-proxy bwowk/browsermob-proxy

3. started Proxy

curl -X POST -d \'port=8081\' http://localhost:58080/proxy

4. creating RemoteWebDriver

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:8081");
String proxyOption = "--proxy-server=" + proxy.getHttpProxy();
options.addArguments(proxyOption);
options.setCapability("enableVNC", true);
options.setCapability("enableVideo", false);
String[] hosts = {"alf.arbetsformedlingen.se:164.135.40.54"};
options.setCapability("hostsEntries", hosts);
String[] containers = {"browser-mob-proxy"};
options.setCapability("applicationContainers", containers);
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://164.135.124.71:4444/wd/hub"), options);
```

Please help understand, what is it i am doing wrong or missing!

Comment: Proxy address certainly should be `browser-mob-proxy:8080`.

Comment: ok i edited but It's still the same! :-/